# ComposeView with view binding

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-viewbinding

I added a `ComposeView` in my XML layout file. I use view binding to inflate this file in my Activity. When I try to call `binding.myComposeView.setContent { ... }` then I get the following compilation error: `Unresolved reference: setContent`. When I take a look at the generated binding file, the type of `myComposeView` is `View` and not `ComposeView`. When I use `findViewById<ComposeView>(R.id.myComposeView).setContent { ... }` then everything works fine. Why is the binding not generated correctly? What can I do to use view binding with a `ComposeView`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that I had two versions of the same layout: portrait and horizontal. I converted the portrait one to Compose by replacing a `LinearLayout` with a `ComposeView`. However, in the horizontal layout `myComposeView` was still a `LinearLayout`. That's why the view binding class that got created had a field `myComposeView` of type `View` instead of `ComposeView`. The view with the same id had different types in two layout versions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a problem with the way the binding is set up in onCreate of your activity. Are you using something along the lines of the following code? :

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
  binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
  val view = binding.root
  setContentView(view)

  binding.composeView.setContent {
    MaterialTheme {
      Text(text = "Hello World")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's more or less how I'm doing it and the type of composeView in the generated binding file is View instead of ComposeView. All other Views work correctly. The problem is just with ComposeViews.